# I imported these modules into Python, what would I write in the buildozer.spec requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, apk, buildozer

I imported these modules into Python, what would I write in the buildozer.spec requirements

```
    import threading
    from functools import partial
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix import *
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import imutils
    import socket
```

I dont know what would I write in the buildozer.spec requirements ?

`requirements = python3,kivy  # what would I write here ?`

Answer (score 1):

`requirements = python3,kivy,opencv-python, imutils`
if you need a specific version write like this:
`requirements = python3,kivy,opencv-python==1.0,imutils`